# Drupal previous and next links

Tags: drupal

At path "events" I have a view showing a list of events sorted by date. Each event title links to path "events/$nid".

On each "events/$nid" page I would like to create previous and next buttons linking to the previous and next events. The previous and the next events has to be determined by the view at path "events".

I would like the anwser to my question to be generic. So the question is really: How do I create previous and next buttons on a node page, where the previous and next nodes are determined by the view from which the first node is accessed.

I am probably building the previous and next buttons as either a block or a panels pane. In this block or panel pane I will be able to call the 'original' view behind the scene and get the previous and next node ids. However, how do I carry the view name between the nodes when the user clicks next several times?

Answer (score 0):

What about putting as 3rd argument?
events/$nid/$view_name

you can then check if the view_name exists with something like

```
 views_get_view(arg(2))
```

* Consider to sanitize the input of arg(2) before use it